# How to manage git-like version control for a text file in Python without using git?

Tags: python, git, version-control

How to keep previous versions of a text file in a similar way to git? **This is about user's configuration of an application and NOT about versioning code.**

I am working with a file which is infrequently updated however need to keep an audit trail of any changes and be able to view previous versions of the file.

The two approaches to achieve this could be:

1. Create a git repository for the file

   - This would require the Python application through which the user updates the file would need to control the git repository and
     make new commits as the file is changed.
2. Save the file with a timestamp each time the file is updated

   - This brings about a file management problem where files can be accidentally deleted, not backed up, etc.

What is the best way to manage versions of text files in Python?

The goal is to have one file which maintains the different versions of the text file.

Comment: You should use `git` or some other version control systems. Why can't you use them?

Comment: You may reconsider your requirement and accept that you want a small database (keeping your many "versions"). Consider *sqlite*

Comment: Maybe you are reinventing wikis.

Comment: you can make your python code itself add and commit your file changes.. you're coding, you must be using some version control anyway.

Comment: @najjarammar What about the deployed environment. What if they don't have git?

Comment: @PeterWood is correct, this is not to track changes to the code but changed to the deployed configuration.

Comment: We version all our configuration files for our production environment the same way we version the code. We have a deployment job which deploys the configuration the same way the binaries are deployed. This means you can only change the configuration in the versioned files, but for us it works just fine.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Allow me to clarify. Lets consider an application like Dropbox, once a user is running it, there are certain settings/configurations which are saved (e.g. start on bootup etc). Now if there is a requirement to keep an audit trail of changes to the settings the user made, how would that be achieved?

Comment: @Simon Please see the comment above (I can only tag one user at a time)

Comment: Maybe consider Mercurial's [**`hglib`**](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PythonHglib). Mercurial is similar to git in many ways, although may be simpler to use and understand (c:. They are both great pieces of software, in my opinion (everyone is entitled to my opinion.) Mercurial is developed in Python and can be used as a Python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a different approach using Git.  If the file is updated infrequently, have a process push the files to Git from the directory on a time interval (1 day?), something like:

```
git add -u
git commit -m "File Audit" && git push
```